# New to coding need help on if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to code an activity we did in class the first 3 if statements work but the last 2 shows an error statement has no effect [-Wunused-value].

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

char getSign()
{

    int grade;
    char Sign;
    cout << "Enter grade: ";
    cin >> grade;

    if(grade == 100)
    {
        Sign = 'A';
    }
    else if(grade == 95)
    {
        Sign = 'B';
    }
    else if(grade == 90)
    {
        Sign = 'C';
    }
    else if(grade == 85)
    {
        Sign == 'D';
    }
    else
    {
        Sign == 'F';
    }
        return Sign;
}


int main()
{
     cout << "Your card grade is: 0" << getSign();
    return 0;
}
```

The result is if I do enter the number 85 or any other number it show 0w

Comment: `=` != `==` know the difference. Also why 99 would yield `F`?

Comment: oh thanks rookie mistake haha and for the 99 our insctrutor told us that those were the only possible grades. We only did pseudocode in class I was trying to put it into code.

Comment: You should be using `<` or `<=`.  For example, in your program, I'll get an 'F' if I have a score of 93.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo `Sign == 'D'`, it should be `Sign = 'D'`. The same for 'F'

Comment: Ohh thanks haha sorry im sort of new to programing :>

Comment: _@robal_ _"You have a typo"_ We have a close reason for such, no need to answer.